# Why my link doesn't have the current route values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is my route

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{testId}/{lg}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", testId = UrlParameter.Optional, lg = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Here is my controller code

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Test/

    public ActionResult Index(int testId,string lg)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index2(int testId, string lg)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Here is my view code (Index.cshtml)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@Url.Action("Index")<br/>

@Url.Action("Index2")
```

When I open "/Test/INdex/1/EN"

This gives me

> /Test/Index/1/EN
>
> /Test/Index2

The first link is ok because it uses the current route value (lg =EN and testId = 1)
But the second is not using the values, I don't get it !

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have expected the first link to have route values, honestly.  Maybe the view engine is smart enough to know that it's linking to the current route and automatically populates them?

In any event, linking to something entirely different isn't going to populate route values by default.  The framework has no reason to believe that those route values are applicable to an entirely different action.

Specify them explicitly:

```
@Url.Action("Index2", new { testId = 1, lg = "EN" })
```

Comment: By design he adds the current route values

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround : the route parameters must be before the action ! :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{testId}/{lg}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", testId = UrlParameter.Optional, lg = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

If someone can say me why...